# Suggestions for HTML5 Canvas sketching libraries

Tags: html, canvas

I am in need of a library/plugin for HTML5 `canvas` that allows you to sketch. I am aware that I can simply create my own script to draw on canvas, but it's the additional functionality that I don't know how to implement. So I'm hoping someone can suggest a library that can add support for:

- Brush manipulation (image, size, color)
- Layered drawing (or a form of 'history')
- Undo support (or again, history)

Does something like this exist? If not can someone send me in the right direction with creating my own functionality like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the undo support but sketch.js is a good place to start.

http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic JS will be a good start ...

http://kineticjs.com/